# Exchange nodes of 3D Model in ARKit

Tags: swift, parent-child, arkit, ios12

I have a car model. This model contains a lot of groups (doors, tires, windows, body). I would like to change the model of the tires by button press. But I have trouble finding the correct node. 
My current idea was to search through all the child nodes of the car and when I find the tires, replace them.

My code:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard anchor is ARImageAnchor else { return }

    guard let carNode = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Car", recursively: false) else { return }
    node.addChildNode(carNode)

@IBAction func tireChangePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
var exchangeTires = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Tires 2")
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in
        if node.name == "Tires"{
// here I try to exchange the node namend "Tires" with the optional node named "Tires 2"
            node = exchangeTires
        }
    }
}
```

But it keeps throwing the error that node is a let constant. Should I use other method to iterate through all the child nodes or what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCNNode and the node tree work analogously to UIView and the view tree, so instead of trying to set the existing node equal to something else you should:

1. Get the parent node of the target with [parent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407968-parent)
2. Remove the target node with [removeFromParentNode()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407991-removefromparentnode)
3. Add the new child node to the parent with [addChildNode(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407974-addchildnode)

Comment: Going to try this in a few! Instructions are clear so far but I did not understand what you meant by pointing out that SCNNode and node tree work analogously to UIView and view tree. Could you explain please?

Comment: You use the same pattern in CoreGraphics, UIKit, SceneKit and SpriteKit.  To remove a node you tell it to remove itself.  to add a node you call addChild on the parent.  They are all Apple API's and share many common design patterns so if you have worked with one, working with the others should be familiar.

Comment: Oh ok got it. Thanks so far. But how does the parent node know, that it should put the new child node exactly on the position the removed node was? In my example: When I delete the old tires, I would like to add the new tires to the exact same place afterwards.

Comment: In the case of SCNNode the children are inherently unordered, so as long as its a child of the same parent its effectively in the same place.  For other things, like UIView or CALayer where the order matters they have insert:before: and insert:after: methods.

Comment: @JoshHomann, I tried this but it won't work. I am not getting where I am wrong. Please check the link where I put my code and let me know is anything missing or wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291659/on-button-click-need-to-change-texture-material-of-child-node-in-arkit-in-ios